# What protocol (http or https) does the browser use to access the server in Ajax calls?

Tags: ajax, http, https

My entire website uses **https**. The website has many JQuery-based ajax calls with the following two formats:

```
$.ajax({
      url: 'getData'  //relative path
```

and

```
$.ajax({
      url: '/account/fetchData'     //absolute path
```

I would like to know whether `http` or `https` are used in these calls. I would like to ensure each Ajax call uses `https`. If an Ajax call does not use `https`, what is the correct link format.

Comment: It uses relative protocols, in other words it will be http if your page is on http and https if it's on https.

Comment: http websocket uses ws:// whereas https uses wss://some.domain